# Scribe Oauth example: LinkedIn, what to input

Tags: scribe

I'm trying the LinkedIn example Oauth in scribe-java lib https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java , now when the code reaches this line, what should I input to the console?

```
System.out.print(">>");
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
System.out.println();
```

The author said the tag to ask is scribe, but it seems too broad?
Thanks

Comment: What is this "LinkedIn example" you speak of?  What does it do, what purpose does it serve?

Comment: It's the LinkedIn example in scribe-java oauth
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first print out your request token like this :

```
System.out.println("REQUEST TOKEN -------> " + requestToken);
requestToken should be like this [axaxaxaxaxaxax, bcbcbcbcbcbcbc] ;
```

copy axaxaxaxaxxa and paste it:

www.linkedin.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=HERE ,

than your browser will print a url with a &oauth_verifier=xxxxxxxxxxxx
copy xxxxxx and paste in your eclipse java project ...